# OpenERP Reports always in PDF

Tags: printing, odoo

I'm new in OpenERP and I'm starting to know the application.

I hope you allow me to post this kind of questions on the forum.

Whenever I issue any listing or report in OpenERP, the application generates a PDF file to be opened or downloaded. Is there any way to make these listings and reports directly into a browser window so I can print them directly from the browser instead of download/open PDF files?

Thank you very much

Paulo Matos

Answer (score 0):

[https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-india/openerp-india/web_pdf_viewer-pga

You can use this module to open directly in browser.

Just copy this module to your web/addons folder of openerp web

Hope its work